# problem with `replace_na()` from tidyr package

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I wrote a function that has five arguments to calculate random numbers from a normal distribution. It has two steps:

1. replace NA with 0 in tibble column
2. replace 0 with a random number

My problems are:

1. line three doesn't replace NA value with 0
2. line five doesn't replace 0 with a random number

I have this error :

```
! Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
x Subscript `col` has the wrong type `function`.
 It must be logical, numeric, or character.
```

here  is my code :

```
whithout=function(col,min,max,mean,sd){
  for(i in 1:4267){
      continuous_dataset=continuous_dataset %>% replace_na(continuous_dataset[,col]=0)
      if(is.na(continuous_dataset[,col])){
         continuous_dataset[i,col]=round(rtruncnorm(1,min,max,mean,sd))    
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to write a function that loops across both columns and observations.

I assume you have no zeroes in your dataset to begin with.  In which case, I can skip replacing `NA` with `0` and go straight to genereating the replacement value.

My solution is based on the tidyverse.

First, generate some test data.

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(x=runif(5), y=runif(5), z=runif(5))
df$x[3] <- NA
df$y[4] <- NA
df$z[5] <- NA
df
# A tibble: 5 × 3
       x       y      z
   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1  0.288  0.0456  0.957
2  0.788  0.528   0.453
3 NA      0.892   0.678
4  0.883 NA       0.573
5  0.940  0.457  NA
```

Now solve the problem.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      everything(), 
      function(.x, mean, sd) .x <- ifelse(is.na(.x), rnorm(nrow(.), mean, sd), .x), 
      mean=500, 
      sd=100
    )
  )
# A tibble: 5 × 3
        x        y       z
    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1   0.288   0.0456   0.957
2   0.788   0.528    0.453
3 669.      0.892    0.678
4   0.883 629.       0.573
5   0.940   0.457  467.
```

By avoiding looping through columns and rows, the code is more compact, more robust and (though I've not tested) faster.

If you don't want to process every column, simply replace `everything()` with a vector of columns that you do want to process.  For example

```
df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(
      c(x, y), 
      function(.x, mean, sd) .x <- ifelse(is.na(.x), rnorm(nrow(.), mean, sd), .x), 
      mean=500, 
      sd=100
    )
  )
# A tibble: 5 × 3
        x        y      z
    <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1   0.288   0.0456  0.957
2   0.788   0.528   0.453
3 669.      0.892   0.678
4   0.883 629.      0.573
5   0.940   0.457  NA
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It works, but how can I define the min and max interval for the random number? Can I round the number?

Comment: You wrote that you wanted to replace `NA`s with values from a Normal distribution.  values from a Normal distribution span the entire real number line.  Your request is inconsistent with your original question.  Nevertheless, the solution would be to adapt the funtion called by `across()` to do the truncation in any manner you wish.

Comment: you're right, but I have a clinical dataset, and I need to put a random number from the standard range of features